# Visual c++ infinite while loop

Tags: visual-c++, while-loop, infinite-loop, 2d-games, visual-studio-express

In visual c++ in express 2013 for Windows desktop I made a ASCII roguelike but the following code is messing it all up.in the game when u defeat.a enemy you get experience which get added to players and levels up if enough.here is the code.it is in a player class I created.
It printed Leveled up to .. no of times I press any key like the while loop never ends .presses a key leveled appears then again I presses a key leveled up appears it keeps on going

```
void Player::addExperience(int experience){_experience += experience;
    while(_experience >50) { 
        _experience -= 50; 
        _level++; 
        printf("Leveled up%s",_level); 
        _getch();
    }
}
```

When I changed the code to ->

```
void Player::addExperience(int experience) {_experience += experience;while(_experience >50) { _experience = 0;_level++/printf("Leveled up%s",_level);
        _getch();
    }
}
```

It printed only one time leveled up to .. So I know the problem is in this code but what. don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I re-read your description few times to understand your problem. I hopt I understood it correctly.

We don't know the value of **experience**. Unless it keeps chaning in the background, the loops are supposed to run infinite number of times OR zero times based on value of **experience**.

The first fragment of code increments level by 1 each time it decreases **_experience** by 50. But, the while loop checks for **experience** instead of **_experience**, so the loop never breaks.